# Shared library not loading. Loading only under root

Tags: permissions, root, environment-variables, shared-library

I have an executable that requires a shared library that resides in `/opt/...` folder. I have included the path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under `/etc/environment` and updated it using `source /etc/environment`. When I run this executable without root permissions, I get an error saying `libxxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. But when I run it with `sudo`, it runs. Though the problem is, the license is not under root user, therefore it throws an error regarding license. I changed the permission for `/opt/...` so that the normal user can create and delete files. Though, it does not help. What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/environment` is interpreted during login. So the correct way to see the changes you made to `/etc/environment` is to logout and login again.

`sudo` works because it partially emulates login as root (`sudo -i` emulates the login even more accurately).

`source /etc/environment` won't work, because `source` is a shell command that tells the shell to interpret the given file as a shell script. The problem is: `/etc/environment` **is not** a shell script. It is a list of **environment variable** name-value pair in the format:

```
name="value"
```

That line, for a shell, is the definition of a **global variable**, which can be seen only by shell itself. Programs executed from the shell can't see it. The correct way to define an environment variable is using the `export` shell command:

```
export name="value"
```

So, if you really want to use your brand new `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` without logging out, you should execute the following command instead of `source /etc/environment`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/..."
```

---

**UPDATE:** `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` cannot be set into `/etc/environment` because of `ssh-agent`. For details see [bug #47958](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/47958) and the Ubuntu wiki page on [environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#File-location_related_variables). As specified in the wiki page, a workaround exists and consists in using `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

For example, you could create `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/opt.conf` with the following contents:

```
# Paths for my cool libraries
/opt/...
```

Although this is listed as a workaround, `ld.so.conf.d` is actually the most appropriate place for such settings.

Comment: Thanks. I logged out and logged in. When I do `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I get nothing. While I executed the same command under root, it prints the path in `/etc/environment`. I execute the `export` command and it's fine now. However, isn't this temporary? If I close the shell, it's gone? Why isn't the non-root user picking the path from the environment file?

Comment: @user592748: you are right. Whilst what I have said is true and applies to the general case, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gets unset by `ssh-agent` during login. I have updated my answer to include a workaround.